# jQuery Cycle with hash permalinks

Tags: jquery, hash, cycle, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to get jQuery Cycle to use unique names from each slide to be able to link to each slide directly. I found this on malsups site: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/perma2.html

Tried to incorporate it in my demo but to no avail, not sure what I'm doing wrong?
**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/uviram/1

Even though I go to `http://jsbin.com/uviram/1#slide2` it still leads me to `http://jsbin.com/uviram/1#slide1`..

```
$(function() {

    var h, 
        hash = window.location.hash, 
        hashes = {},
        index = 0;

    $('.slideshow slide').each(function(i) {
        h = $(this).data('hash');
        hashes[h] = i;
    });

    if (hash)
        index = hashes[hash.substring(1)] || index;

    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        timeout: 0,
        prev: $('.prev'),
        next: $('.next'),
        after: function(curr,next,opts) {
            h = $(this).data('hash');
            window.location.hash = h;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok so what code are you using?

Comment: @TomWalters Updated with code snippet now, entire code is available in the demo I linked to!

Comment: Change `$(function() {` to `$(document).ready(function() {`?

Comment: @Mooseman They have exactly the same effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your jsbin demo so it works now. There were three problems:

- Firstly, I changed `$('.slideshow slide')` to `$('.slideshow
  .slide')` to correctly select the slides.
- Secondly, I put the startingSlide option into the cycle call.
- Lastly, I put in a hashchange listener so that if the user changes
  the hash without reloading the page, it will cycle to the correct
  slide.

Take a look at your updated demo to see it working:

http://jsbin.com/uviram/6#slide4

Comment: might want to take a look at `cycle2`. Has a lot of new features  http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/ including responsive layout and auto initialization

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the `startingSlide` option to pass your `index` to

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
        /* pass index to startingSlide*/
        startingSlide:index,
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        timeout: 0,
        prev: $('.prev'),
        next: $('.next'),
        after: function(curr,next,opts) {
            h = $(this).data('hash');
            window.location.hash = h;
        }
});
```